# Несколько PriorityQueue

Tags: java

Допустим у меня есть несколько PriorityQueue, в одном процессе туда подкидываются значения, а второй процесс разгребает их.
Для начала второй процесс проверяет есть ли что-то в них методом peek() а потом вытягивает методом poll(), но иногда, если повезет и первый процесс сделает записи так быстро что в одной из очередей окажется более 1-2 записей, то второй процесс отказывается работать а иногда NullPointerException выскакивает, как быть? Также пробовал размер очереди сравнивать с нулём - то-же самое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. PriorityQueue не потокобезопасен. Следовательно доступ к нему должен быть синхронизирован.
2. NullPointerException не объясняет проблему без соответствующего стектрейса. Но рискну предположить, что вы пытаетесь положить null в очередь. PriorityQueue не поддерживает nullable значения.

Все это описано в javadoc к классу [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) и чтение документации, скорее всего, помогло бы вам в решении проблемы.

Comment: По первому понял, не придал значения при чтении документации, а по второму, исключение дает второй процесс, он же не может положить null, или может?

Comment: Может или не может - вам виднее. Вы же код пишете.

NPE может быть причиной п.1 из ответа. Опять же, без стектрейса можно только гадать.